# How make a generic type in java?

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends, implements

I want make my List. But I dont know how to write generic type in java.

---

```
public interface myListInt <E extends Comparable<E>>{}
```

---

```
public class myList<E extends myListInt<E>> extends LinkedList{}
```

---

When I am doing that, it gives an error.How should ı write.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do. All you've said is so far is "I want make my List".

Answer (score 0):

The exact intent of your code is unclear, but I got an error for the `<E>` in `myListInt<E>`.

```
public interface myListInt <E extends Comparable<E>>{}
public class myList<E extends myListInt<E>> extends LinkedList{}
                                        ^ Error here
```

This is because you need to constrain `E` to extend `Comparable<E>` in order to be a valid bound for `myListInt<E>`:

```
public class myList<E extends Comparable<E> & myListInt<E>>
    extends LinkedList{}
```

However, you maybe also want to add a constraint to `LinkedList` too (assuming this is `java.util.LinkedList`:

```
public class myList<E extends Comparable<E> & myListInt<E>>
    extends LinkedList<E> {}
```